# Clarification in Java Package structure

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have to add a filter in the web.xml of my web app which uses the directory structure which is in a jar file which I'll be adding to my lib directory of my web app.

```
<filter>
                <filter-name>monitor</filter-name>
                <filter-class>com.student.compute</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>monitor</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

Here the filter is using the "compute" class from the com.student package in the jar file. I have expanded the jar file and have confirmed whether this structure exists.

Now in my classes directory I too have a com directory which houses many classes specific to my application.

Now won't the com in the jar file and the com in the classes directory clash when I try to access content in my web application.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they won't clash. If that was a problem, you couldn't use several libraries from, fo example, Apache at the same time, because they all put their classes under some sub-package of org.apache.

You can see the package tree of all the classes in the classpath as a giant tree containing a merge of all the package trees of all the jars and directories listed in the classpath.

If you had two classes with the exact same package and name in two different jars/directories in the classpath, then that would be a problem, because only the first one would be available, and you can't (AFAIK) have any guarantee about the order of the WEB-INF/classes and jars under WEB-INF/lib in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks. How can I see that package trees of all the jars and directories listed in the classpath.

Comment: Except by merging all the jars by yourself, you can't. But why would you want to see that? The only thing that matters is that if a class is in one of the jars, it's available, whatever other classes exist in whatever other jars.

Answer (score 0):

Although they look hierarchical, packages in Java are not. A package

`com.student.compute`

is not "underneath"

`com.student`

it is just another distinct package.

In your web application if you have two jar files that contain exactly the same package (in your case for example both could contain`com.student.compute`) the classloader will search all of the jars to find your classes and will "return" the first one if finds. This can be a source of a lot of problems and is best avoided.

Exactly how the classloader works depends upon the environment. The web servlet engine for example uses a different classloader for each web application so that your jars do not conflict and you cannot see jars loaded by other web applications.